# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Tags: java, android, json

I'm following tutorial to register but data can't be sent to the database because of an error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

And here's the code :

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener {

    private AppCompatButton btn_register;
    private EditText et_email,et_password,et_name;
    private TextView tv_login;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        btn_register = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        tv_login = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_login);
        et_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        et_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tv_login:
                goToLogin();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_register:

                String name = et_name.getText().toString();
                String email = et_email.getText().toString();
                String password = et_password.getText().toString();

                if(!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    registerProcess(name,email,password);

                } else {

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    private void registerProcess(String name, String email,String password){


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }

    private void goToLogin(){

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line of code is producing the error? Is there a stack trace to go with the error message? Are you parsing some JSON at the time? Please edit your question to include the JSON.

Comment: You will get more feedback if the posted source code is not this big. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `RequestInterface` does not match what your server is returning, apparently.

Comment: i dont know @CommonsWare , but can you help me please , im trying to follow tutorial : this is server side : https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-server.html        and here is the client side : https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-client.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);
```

Retrofit is expecting an object but it's receiving an array.

Comment: so what can i do to solve it ?? im beginner in this :(

Comment: @Fatima use a `Call<List<ServerResponse>>` instead